# send activate-email with django-registration

Tags: python, django, django-registration

I am curious if there's a way to send activated email with username, password by using django-registration. First I thought about modifying registration form but I need some example.

Comment: Do NOT send user passwords in email.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[django-registration](https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/) uses the following code, internally, to handle sending emails:

```
send_mail(subject, message, settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL, [self.user.email])
```

If you want to work, you will have to specify the value DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL in your settings.py.

Also, note the following:

> Mail is sent using the SMTP host and
>   port specified in the EMAIL_HOST  and
>   EMAIL_PORT  settings. The
>   EMAIL_HOST_USER  and
>   EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD  settings, if set,
>   are used to authenticate to the SMTP
>   server, and the EMAIL_USE_TLS  setting
>   controls whether a secure connection
>   is used.

So, to give an example, here's what I've used in a settings.py file to use a gmail account:

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 465
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True

EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'my@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'my_emails_password'
```

[django-registration](https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/) should then be able to send emails.

Comment: And, just for the record, to anyone else setting up email - **don't** make the mistake I did, of using quotes around the port, as in `EMAIL_PORT='587'`. That cost me a few hours of debugging...

Comment: thanks to your tip, i double checked my errant email config - only to discover that 4 lines after setting it up with a gmail account, i had set it up for some nonsense localhost account! Problem? Solved.

Comment: I think we must use `EMAIL_PORT = 587` when `EMAIL_USE_TLS = True`

Answer (score 3):

EMAIL_PORT = 465 was working some year ago. Now you need to use port 587 with gmail.
Reason: Django does not support SMTP with SSL from the beginning. Only STARTTLS command is supported AFTER plain-text connection is set up. Gmail, however, no longer supports this option on port 465.

Answer (score 2):

Hope this will help someone. After troubleshooting for half an hour, I realised that I had to explicitly state this as well while using django-registration -

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'

Answer (score 0):

[django-register-activate](https://github.com/JunyiJ/django-register-activate) implemented a similar functionality as django-registration. Basically it provides code for user sign up, email verification and activation, user login and user logout.

If you need examples to implement your own code, you may check the views.py and forms.py in [register_activate](https://github.com/JunyiJ/django-register-activate/tree/master/register_activate) to get some hints.

Hope the answer helps. Let me know if you have further questions.